# Need a menu inside hamburger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I have a hamburger menu below :

[image: Hamburger Menu]

And I want something like this :

[image: Requirement]

In above image, item 4 has another menu inside of it and I wish to create the same for my hamburger menu.

Code for my hamburger is :

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* background-color: #111; */
    background-color: #45169B;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: medium;
    /* color: #818181; */
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
        border-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

/* #main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
} */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
.menu{z-index:1000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:0.8em; width:100%; background:#f1f1f1;  position:absolute; text-align:center; font-size:12px;}
.leftFloat{
    float:left;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px !important;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

And the HTML :

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="white closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>

                        <a href="#" id="refresh" class="white" style="border-top: 1px solid black;"><i class="fa fa-refresh white" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Refresh</a>    
                        <a class="white excelPointer" href="fleetonmapvts.html" id="fleetOnMap"><i class="fa fa-map-marker white" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Fleet On Map</a>
                        <a href="schedulereportsvts.html" id="scheduleReportsli" class="white"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart white" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Schedule Reports</a>
                        <a href="javascript:showMoadlAddReports()" id="showReportAdd" class="white"><i class="fa fa-tasks white" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Add Reports</a>
                        <a href="#" class="white" id="logout"><i class="fa fa-power-off white" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Logout</a>
                    </div>
```

How can I achieve this using css ??

Anyone can help me out here ?

Comment: You need to add another ul within the li you want and then style it to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129037/correct-semantics-for-ul-in-ul#answer-12129070

Comment: actually in my code, I have not used any lists.. I just tried it and didnt work.. I need anything apart that..

Comment: actually it is easier to suit it to your needs, style it and more semantically correct when they are lists - please check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160859/one-line-vertical-menu-with-submenus-pure-css

Answer (score 1):

Use this as per your markup. Since your css code was not working properly.
I have created basic markup and js functionality.

```js
$(function(){
   $(".has-submenu").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).nextAll('.level2').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
   });
  })
```

```css
a{
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
   color: #444;
   text-decoration: none;
   border: 1px solid #222;
  }
  .level2 {
   padding-left: 35px;
   background-color: #efefef;
   display: none;
  }
  .caret {
   float: right;
   border-top: 15px solid #ccc;
   border-right: 7px solid transparent;
   border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  }
  .active {
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
  }
  .active .caret{
   border-top: none;
   border-bottom: 15px solid #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#" class="level-1">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#" class="level-1">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#" class="level-1 has-submenu">
   Lorem
   <i class="caret"></i>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="level2">
   Sub menu
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="level2">
   Sub menu
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="level2">
   Sub menu
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="level2">
   Sub menu
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="level-1">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#" class="level-1">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#" class="level-1">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#" class="level-1">Lorem</a>
  <a href="#" class="level-1">Lorem</a>
 </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```